# Arch linux wifi works manually, how to make it automatic?

Tags: linux, wifi, arch-linux

Running Arch Linux with kernel 3.6.11-12-ARCH+ on my Raspberry Pi.

I have a Linksys wifi usb dongle (WUSB54GC v3) that is running and working after I execute the following commands:

```
$> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
$> sudo iwlist scan
$> sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed essid myssid key "mykey" retry 7
   # Only had to do this next one the first time
$> sudo wpa_passphrase myssid "mypassword" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
$> sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
$> sudo dhcpcd wlan0
```

How do I get wifi on this device to work every time after booting?  Eventually I want to deploy it in location without a wired connection (hence the wifi), but I obviously can't do that if I have to manually start/connect the wifi every time.

Comment: Wireless is best managed via a daemon such as `network-manager` or `wicd`.

Comment: Did you try this instruction to automatically connect to wireless  networks: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netcfg

Comment: netcfg is depreciated in favour of netctl (not sure if that change has been reflected in the ARM respin of Arch yet though), but yes that is the way to handle your network config.

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59278/how-can-i-enable-wpa_supplicant-on-boot/

Answer (score 24):

You should use netctl.  It is the Arch Linux built in network management system.  If it isn't already installed (it should be though), run `pacman -Syu netctl` then look in `/etc/netctl`.  There are example configuration files in `/etc/netctl/examples`.

To get up and running quickly:

1. Make note of the device name for your wireless adapter.  Replace all instances of `wlan0` in my examples with the name that matches your setup.
2. Ensure you have installed the required packages.

   > `pacman -Syu wpa_supplicant dhcpcd`

   1. wpa_supplicant is required for WPA protected access points, and dhcpcd is required to get an IP from any network using a DHCP server, as listed on the Arch Linux wiki.
3. Copy an appropriate example:

   > `cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa /etc/netctl/somedescriptivename`
4. Edit your new config at `/etc/netctl/somedescriptivename` to fit your setup.
5. Enable the `netctl-auto` service for your wireless adapter.  Again, replace `wlan0` with the device name for your setup.

   > `systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlan0.service`

A few things to note:

- netctl will automatically connect to any profiles you have in /etc/netctl when you move into range of the access point
- This setup will only work with profiles using `Security=wpa-configsection` and `Security=wpa`.
- Disable all previously enabled wifi profiles using `netctl disable profilename`. Otherwise netctl will start them twice at boot once netctl-auto is enabled.

For more information please refer to [the Netctl wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl).

Comment: that `netctl-auto list` returns no profiles, whereas 4 are configured and work with manual netctl is expected or anormal ? How can I use `netctl-auto switch-to X` if there are seemingly no valid X values ? I find the netctl-auto arch wiki entry surprisingly unhelpful, maybe you know where to find a better doc ?

Comment: Nikana, I don't use `netctl-auto` very much, but just a few tips:
1. `netctl-auto` is for wireless connections only.  If you're looking to use it for ethernet, use netctl-ifplugd.
2. Make sure you do not use `wpa-config` as the security method, and instead of `wpa-configsection` or `wpa`.  Profiles will not show up when using `wpa-config`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for future viewers, my setup works now, not that I recall doing anything special. `netctl-auto list` returns a bunch of profiles as it should. I think maybe one of my profiles was not compatible with netctl-auto because of this no-`wpa-config` requirement, which prevented all of them from showing up.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you need to remove profiles created with netctl before enabling netctl-auto. Then, after starting netctl-auto, re-add them.

Comment: You would not use wlan0 as shown here. You have to use your correct WiFi ID.

Comment: "Starting with version 1.20, netctl stopped depending on wpa_actiond for its automatic wireless connecting features" https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61934

Comment: @johnywhy it's actually not true that you need to "remove" the profiles.  You simply need to disable them, as per the netctl wiki entry.  netctl-auto will automatically enable them as you move into range of a given SSID.  Please refer to the notes in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless

Answer (score 7):

An easier way that eliminates some of the guesswork on how to make profiles for `netctl` (taken from the [`netctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl) page on the arch wiki):

Step 1. Setup wireless internet manually, using `wpa_supplicant` as described in the OP.
If your system doesn't have it installed do `$ pacman -S wpa_supplicant`.

Step 2. You'll also need `dialog` package, so `$ pacman -S dialog`. Then, you could either reboot your system or disconnect from your wireless network.

Step 3. Run `$ wifi-menu -o`, then go through the very straightforward Windows/Mac-esque settings. You can check the preset value of your system's network id via `$ sudo netctl list`. The value would be in the format of `wlan098-SSID`. (where SSID = your WLAN's name)

Step 4. Finally run `$ netctl enable wlan098-SSID` and reboot the system `$ reboot`

Still, occasionally you might get an error message with something like **`temporarily unable to resolve name`** or something, but just try pinging again and it should work.

Comment: Without netctl-auto, you won't reconnect automatically as hotspots come within range. See my answer for set up.

Answer (score 3):

I believe all other answers are flawed, as explained in my comments on them.

These steps will auto-connect to the strongest hotspot. Tested on a standard arch install with systemd (may work on other OS's):

**One-time setup:**

- Ensure the following are installed: dialog, wpa_supplicant, dhcpcd, netctl, wifi-menu.
- On xfce, add the xfce4-wavelan-plugin, and add it to your panel of choice. That's just an indicator light which shows when you're connected. It has no other purpose.
- Ensure all other network managers and services are removed or disabled. 
  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless
- Remove any previously created network profiles.
  https://www.ostechnix.com/fix-job-netctl-service-failed-error-arch-linux/

Alternatively, just disable them, as explained by @JacobWiltse in a comment on another answer. [wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wireless)

- Obtain your WiFi device ID
  `basename $(ls -d /sys/class/net/w*)`
- enable netctl-auto service. This is the service that will auto connect. 
  `systemctl enable netctl-auto@YourWifiDeviceID.service`

**Connect to a hotspot first time:**

- Run `wifi-menu`. Requires root. 
  `pkexec wifi-menu -o`
  or
  `sudo wifi-menu -o`

Leave off the `-o` to see network passwords as you type it.

- Arrow down, pick your desired connection, hit enter, accept connection-name, enter password.

Add more hotspots as needed. netctl-auto will automatically reconnect to the strongest available hotspot thereafter.

Comment: Answer improved