# Manjaro Connect SSH & Wifi before log in

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, openssh, manjaro

I have fresh installed Manjaro version 17. Then I install OpenSSH, My aim is to start SSH on boot. SO I did below

```
sudo pacman -Sy openssh
sudo systemctl start  sshd.service
sudo systemctl enable  sshd.service
```

I enable Firewall too, at every boot I have to login to system than only I can connect to SSH. I also enable

```
sudo systemctl start sshd.socket
sudo systemctl enable sshd.socket
```

But still same. I am using Wifi and I feel that until I login my wifi is not connecting and it is not getting IP due to that SSH is not work.

[image]

Kindly somebody help me.

Comment: What errors you get? Do you have encrypted home? Do not enable both `sshd.service` and `sshd.socket`. They conflict each other and `systemd` is not able to cope with that.

Comment: Connection time out from SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use netctl.  It is the Arch Linux built in network management system.  If it isn't already installed (it should be though), run `pacman -Syu netctl` then look in `/etc/netctl`.

There are example configuration files in `/etc/netctl/examples`.  To use an example, just copy it to `/etc/netctl` and edit it to fit your set up.  So for your case, run `cp /etc/netctl/example/wireless-wpa /etc/netctl/somedescriptivename` then edit `/etc/netctl/somedescriptivename` to fit your set up.

To enable auto configuration of your wireless networks with systemd, make sure the `wpa_actiond` package is installed and enable the service: `systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlan0.service`

For more information please refer to [the Netctl wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl).

From : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83108/237568

Comment: Hi, I could not find  /etc/network/interfaces, I think missing

Comment: Can you add the output of ip addr, and your /etc/netctl. I forgot that for Manjaro it is /etc/netctl.

Comment: i updated my question with requested data

Comment: Please check my answer, I updated the answer.

Comment: Don't you think netctl and NetworkManager will conflict

Comment: It could. Can you try this: systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlp0s29ulu6 . And then, restart and check.

Comment: No still error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62317/discussion-between-milind-and-hunter-s-thompson).